# Azure Releases Pipeline - newman test - publish test results failed with "The following extension fields were not found: TestRunSystem"

Tags: azure-devops, newman, azure-devops-server-2019

I have a simple newman test implemented on Azure release pipeline.
The test is working, however when it try to publish the test results I got this warning:

"**The following extension fields were not found: TestRunSystem**"

and no tests results of course.

Any idea?

[image: pipeline]

[image: error message]

[image: publish task results setting]

Comment: Please check  task `Publish Test Results` if the field  `Test result format` is set to `JUnit`.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Yes, I did. all the settings are correct

Comment: What version of Azure DevOps/TFS are you on? 2.143.4 is quite old... what version of Azure DevOps are you on, because I'm guessing you're on Azure DevOps Server, not cloud.

Comment: @jessehouwing You are right, we are using Server not cloud. and we are on version AzureDevOps 2019 17.143.28621.4.

Comment: Could you check out [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/3768) and try upgrading the Publish Test Results task version. Or try upgrade your agent version to the latest. If not working. Please try upgrading your Azure DevOps.

Comment: Thanks @LeviLu-MSFT we are planning to upgrade our DevOps to the newest in March. Hope that will fix the issue.