# Azure release pipeline - publish test results - Tests Tab - TFS.WebApi.Exception: System field FailingSince not found

Tags: azure-devops, newman, azure-devops-server-2019

I have a very simple release pipeline using newman test, and publish the results.

[image: Release Pipeline]

[image: Publish test Results setting]

The "Publish Test Results" was successful and I can access the results via the link inside.

[image: Publish Test Results]

However, when I try to access the results via "Tests" tab, I got this error.

**TFS.WebApi.Exception: System field FailingSince not found**

[image: Error message]

Anyone know why?  Thanks.

PS: Currently, I'm using version 1.* for "Publish Test Results". If I switch to version 2.*, I will get another set of error here: [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66266758/azure-releases-pipeline-newman-test-publish-test-results-failed-with-the-fo)

Comment: What version of Azure DevOps/TFS are you on? 2.143.4 is quite old... what version of Azure DevOps are you on, because I'm guessing you're on Azure DevOps Server, not cloud.

Comment: @jessehouwing You are right, we are using Server not cloud. and we are on version AzureDevOps 2019 17.143.28621.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the stored process below to resolve the issue.

Find the dataspace ID and partition ID from the below query on the collection DB

```
SELECT PartitionId, DataspaceId FROM dbo.tbl_Project where PartitionId >0 and ProjectName = ‘<tfs project name>’
```

Use the partitionID and dataspaceID from above query on the fields table to see if the appropriate FailingSince field is present

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_TestFieldsEx WHERE PartitionId =<partitionID> AND DataspaceId = <dataspaceID>
```

This should not return a row with the field for FailingSince

Update the table as below

```
insert into @p3 values(N'StackTrace',12,0,1,1)

insert into @p3 values(N'FailingSince',12,0,1,1)

insert into @p3 values(N'Comment',12,0,1,1)

insert into @p3 values(N'ErrorMessage',12,0,1,1)

insert into @p3 values(N'OutcomeConfidence',6,0,1,1)

insert into @p3 values(N'TestRunSystem',12,1,0,1)

insert into @p3 values(N'AttemptId',8,0,1,1)

insert into @p3 values(N'UnsanitizedTestCaseTitle',12,0,1,1)

insert into @p3 values(N'UnsanitizedAutomatedTestName',12,0,1,1)

insert into @p3 values(N'TestResultGroupType',12,0,1,1)

insert into @p3 values(N'MaxReservedSubResultId',8,0,1,1)


exec prc_AddTestExtensionFields @partitionId=<partitionID>,@dataspaceId=<dataspaceID>,@fieldsTable=@p3
```

This should update at least one row

Run the above-read query again to see that the FailingSince field is present.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_TestFieldsEx WHERE PartitionId =<partitionID> AND DataspaceId = <dataspaceID>
```

This should not return a row with the field for FailingSince

Comment: Thanks Vito, any idea why this error happened? is that mean our devop database is missing some table/field?

Comment: I don't confirm the root cause of this error. By the way, does the answer resolved your question?

Comment: we haven't tried it out yet, just curious why the DB are missing some system field. Will select the answer once I tried this out.

Comment: you could try it and kindly share the result here, If you have any questions about this ticket, you could also share it here and we will continue to solve the problem for you here. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Our team decided to do a fresh install of DevOp Server in March with the newest version, so will be able to test it then.

Comment: Upgrade the DevOp Server or install the newest version? You could also try the workaround in the current version, it should be work, if install the newest version, I recommend that install TFS2020, I have test it and it works. By the way, If this answer is helpful, would you please accept it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)